# what is the cardinality of each of these sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am confused on these questions I feel like that are too easy. I just need to find the cardinality of each of the 3 problems. I believe that the first one and third one is a zero with a slash through it. Then the second question I believe is 3. Can anyone veryify this for me please.

1. $\{ x \colon x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x^2=2 \}$
2. $\{a,b , \{a,b\} \}$
3. $\{x \colon x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } x^2=2 \}$

Comment: what about $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Number 3 _is_ the empty set; its cardinality is $0$ (zero), not $\emptyset$ (the empty set).

Answer (score 1):

The first one has two elements in it:
\begin{equation}
\{x \ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}, x^2=2\}=\{\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2\}\end{equation} so its cardinality is 2.

The second set has 3 elements in it so its cardinality is 3 and finally the last one is the empty set so its  cardinality is zero.